# MySQL query returns false if a COUNT-SELECT in the query returns nothing

Tags: mysql

Using the following, I'm getting a null set because the inner select returns nothing. I want the results of the wishlist table entry (which is there) with 0 for the count. I thought this would do it, but apparently not?

```
SELECT *, (
                SELECT COUNT(*)
                FROM wl_items
                WHERE wl_id = wishlists.id
            ) as item_count
            FROM wishlists
            WHERE wishlists.id=5
```

Comment: If this query returns an empty resultset, it means that there is no `wishlist` with `id` `5`. Sample data and desired results would help clarifying what you ask for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query feels like you could do it more simply as a join:

```
SELECT wishlists.*, COUNT(wl_id)
FROM wishlists LEFT JOIN wl_items ON (wl_id = wishlists.id)
WHERE wishlists.id=5;
```

Comment: Excellent alternative, though in testing it I determined that the row with id 5 is actually NOT there (SMH). Thank you. I will mark as answered because thisis a completely viable alternative.